# How to ignore hidden objects on match on HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, match

I'm trying to match visible object's text but ignore not visible ones. By the way I need HTML code.

Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/sundowatch/pen/qBEmooj).

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="main">
   <div class="a">Hello</div>
   <div class="hid">Hello</div>
   <div class="b">Hello</div>
   <div class="hid2">Hello</div>
   <div class="c">Hello</div>
   <div class="hid3">Hello</div>
   <div class="hid4">Hello</div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.hid, .hid2, .hid3, .hid4{
   display: none;
}
```

My JavaScript:

```
var regEx = /Hello/g;

var main = $('.main').html();

var matches = main.match(regEx);

console.log(matches);
```

Actually I want to exclude invisible elements without removing them from page. I want these HTML codes at the result:

```
<div class="a">Hello</div>
<div class="b">Hello</div>
<div class="c">Hello</div>
```

I don't want to remove the hidden objects because I'll use them interactively. I just want to exclude them from match. We can use jQuery.

Thank you from now.

Comment: Working with HTML as a string is not good practice. What is the output you're trying to get?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `:visible` selector like `$('.main div:visible')`

```js
var visible = $('.main div:visible').map((_,i) => i.outerHTML).get();
console.log(visible);
```

```css
.hid, .hid2, .hid3, .hid4{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
   <div class="a">Hello</div>
   <div class="hid">Hello</div>
   <div class="b">Hello</div>
   <div class="hid2">Hello</div>
   <div class="c">Hello</div>
   <div class="hid3">Hello</div>
   <div class="hid4">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:visible` selector to find all the divs under `.main` which are not hidden, and then output their `outerHTML` value if they match the regex:

```js
var regEx = /Hello/g;

var visible = $('.main div:visible');
visible.each(function () {
   if ($(this).text().match(regEx)) {
      console.log(this.outerHTML)
   }
});
```

```css
.hid, .hid2, .hid3, .hid4{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
   <div class="a">Hello</div>
   <div class="hid">Hello</div>
   <div class="b">Hllo</div>
   <div class="hid2">Hello</div>
   <div class="c">Hello</div>
   <div class="hid3">Hello</div>
   <div class="hid4">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var regEx = /Hello/g;
$(".main div:visible").each(function(val, html){
   let inerHTML = $(this).html();
   console.log(inerHTML.match(regEx))
})
```